# R penalized fails with Lapack dtrtrs matrix inversion error

Tags: r, lapack, logistic-regression

In trying to run optL1 from the R penalized package, with the logistic model:

```
optL1(OS_event_ID, sdf, data=sdf, model='logistic', standardize=TRUE, fold=10)
```

... I am then encountered with an error that seems to be related to a dependency:

```
error code 46 from Lapack routine 'dtrtrs'
Error : Matrix inversion failed. Please increase lambda1 and/or lambda2
```

Does anyone have any insight on how to get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem quite a few times so i decided to check the manual and found something helpful. The algorithm for optimized lambda obtention is not robust with any distribution of the variables, quoted:

> "When using this algorithm, it is important to realize that this
>   algorithm is guaranteed to work only for unimodal functions and that
>   it may converge to a local maximum".

Indeed, bimodal distributions are more likely to produce convergence trouble.

[[1]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/vignettes/penalized.pdf](http://I%20faced%20the%20same%20problem%20quite%20a%20few%20times%20so%20i%20decided%20to%20check%20the%20manual%20and%20found%20something%20helpful.%20The%20algorithm%20for%20optimized%20lambda%20obtention%20is%20not%20robust%20with%20any%20distribution%20of%20the%20variables,%20quoted:%20%22When%20using%20this%20algorithm,%20it%20is%20important%20to%20realize%20that%20this%20algorithm%20is%20guaranteed%20to%20work%20only%20for%20unimodal%20functions%20and%20that%20it%20may%20converge%20to%20a%20local%20maximum%22.%20Indeed,%20bimodal%20distributions%20are%20more%20likely%20to%20produce%20convergence%20trouble.%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/vignettes/penalized.pdf)